# PHP Session variables automatically assigned to regular variables

Tags: php, session

I'm hosted at IX webhosting, and I came across something that struck me as strange. All my $_SESSION variables are automatically assigned to a regular variable of the same name. Is that normal PHP behavior? I looked it up in the php.net manual and didn't find an answer. Here's an example script:

```
<?php
$_SESSION['myvar'] = "hello";
echo $myvar; // after a page refresh, displays hello

$myvar = "goodbye";
echo $_SESSION['myvar']; // displays goodbye
?>
```

On my localhost I get an error msg in the likes of undefined variable: $myvar but at IX, the script works! Hazardous or normal PHP behavior? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What @zerkms said. And this is why everyone makes fun of PHP.

Comment: It is quite a crazy feature. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "feature" controlled by a php.ini directive called [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php). It has been disabled by default since PHP 4.2 and totally removed in PHP 5.4.

Unless you have legacy code depending on it, I would sincerely recommend that you **turn it off if you can**. Suffice to say, the security implications are pretty major.

Comment: And if you can't turn it off, consider switching web hosts.  :P  Yeah...it's that bad.

Comment: It is incredibly bad. They only offer to turn it off with a custom cgi php.ini called from a .htaccess file ... Is that safe/efficient enough?

Comment: @bobdope As long as you can turn it off site wide with a single .htaccess file, it should be a perfectly ok solution. Of course default off would be a better solution, if you set another account up, you'll otherwise have to remember to do the same thing again.